# Database Schema Error

Tags: database, visual-studio, schema, datalist

When I use the Data-List object in Visual Studio 2008 while creating a website, and select a data source, after I choose my data source and click OK it gives me this error:
[alt text http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2009/07_w28/t157215/errormessage.jpg](http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2009/07_w28/t157215/errormessage.jpg)

I've searched the net and found that:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlexpress/thread/43357002-3895-4fd4-aee2-59f86d594e70

I Installed the "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Objects" and the "Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types" (this is must in order to install the management objects), restarted my computer, but i still have this problem.

Does someone have any idea what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is saying that you either can't access the specified SQL Server (network connectivity problem) OR the specified credentials in your connection string (Windows Integrated or SQL Server) don't have permissions to the specified database and server combination.  Provider some more details and you'll probably get some more help...